Using curlpp, compiles well but then execution error
This the example code I am using: curlpp_example_00
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>


using namespace curlpp::options;

int main(int, char **)
{
    try
    {
        // That's all that is needed to do cleanup of used resources (RAII style).
        curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

        // Our request to be sent.
        curlpp::Easy myRequest;

        // Set the URL.
        myRequest.setOpt<Url>("http://example.com");

        // Send request and get a result.
        // By default the result goes to standard output.
        myRequest.perform();
    }

    catch(curlpp::RuntimeError & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    catch(curlpp::LogicError & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    
  return 0;
}

I have curl and curlpp libraries installed. I have also linked the curl.dll.a and curlpp.dll.a linker files when I compile the code using this command:
g++ http_demo_1.cpp -o myprogram -L"C:\msys64\mingw64\lib" -lcurlpp -lcurl

And then I run my program:
./myprogram

There is no compilation error, but the execution does not happen, and the terminal shows this (I am using VScode):

It just says:

Command executed and failed. Exit code 1

There is nothing else.  What am I missing here?

It likely can't find dynamic libraries libcurl and perhaps libcurlpp.

Where are the .dlls for curl located? Are they in a folder that you OS is looking?

Stack Overflow Usage note: Show text as text. There are many good reasons for this, but most important is images are still hard to search, and if future askers cannot search for and find this question, it's not a useful addition to Stack Overflow's library of solutions. If you have code, build diagnostic messages, program console output, program input, or what-have-you copy them as text and paste the text into the question.

This if the .dlls are in a folder your OS already looks this problem could also be a dll conflict called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell meaning you have some incompatible dlls of the same name as the ones you are building with and your OS loaded the incompatible ones because when searching they were found first. This msdn document describes how windows searches for dlls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps

My advice is to start by compiling and running your code from a msys2 terminal. If that works then you know the PATH is likely your problem.

Very minor side note : catch your exceptions by const&

start by printing the error code with echo %ERRORLEVEL% or even better using a debugger

@drescherjm I have in fact kept all the dlls in system32 and system32 is in PATH. I had a quick fix though, i just copied the dlls files into the folder my executable was in and then it worked but it looks infeasible to copy dlls into every folder i have executables in, so I am still in need of a permanent solution.
Side Note: I used dependency walker to find the missing dlls for the executable and only put those in my current executables folder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-unpackaged-apps gives you all the options on where to put the dependent dlls. For my work projects I usually create  a single bin/Debug bin/Release folder and have CMake put the dependent dlls (through scripting) to these folders. Many of my projects will have 5 to 10 different executables and they will go to this folder. For installation I create a NSIS based installer.

@drescherjm Thanks for the link, I am kinda curious why for some reason even though my dlls are present both in PATH and system 32 which are both used in the search order, the linker failed to get either. I will try to reinstall the dlls and test what's going wrong. Thanks for the help.

The linker isn't the problem if you have an executable. The problem of your program not running at runtime is caused the way your OS searches for dlls and what it found during the search. Also you should never put files in your OS folders. I suspect you put the wrong 32/64 bit dlls in your OS folder and that created the problem that caused your application to not execute.
